# minio for mariadb in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, storage, azure-storage, minio

I'm running a k3s single node cluster and have the `k3s local-path-provisioner` as storage. As I want to be able to **add nodes in the future**, I looked at minio to use on top of the local-path as storage. But I'm not sure if it's the right choice, cause I my workloads primarily use **mariadb** for data and I read, that an s3 compatible bucket isn't the best for database applications.

I hope you can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use object storage then here are your options for running a local storage provisioner:

- GlusterFS StorageClass
  Doesn't have lot of documentation on how to set it up. But if you know your way around GlusterFS It'll be a good option.
- [local-path-provisioner](https://github.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner/tree/master/deploy/chart)
  I
  t provides a way for the Kubernetes users to utilize the local storage in each node
- OpenEBS -> has a local volume storage engine but I think this is not designed to work on a shared volume mount and it end up tying a pod to a specific node since the data "doesn't exist" on the other nodes.
- longhorn [recommened]

  It creates a dedicated storage controller for each block device volume and synchronously replicates the volume across multiple replicas stored on multiple nodes.
- [rook](https://rook.io/)

Rook is a storage operators for Kubernetes, It supports multiple storage backends. Don't use the NFS one tho cause we hit a wall when using it with our DBs.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial for deploying longohrn with helm? I just can't figure it out wit the [official tutorial](https://longhorn.io/docs/1.0.2/advanced-resources/deploy/customizing-default-settings/#using-helm) what all the values are for

Comment: Check out their installation docs it's pretty decent https://longhorn.io/docs/1.0.2/deploy/install/install-with-helm/